# Determining the Value of Inhibition constant

Tags: enzyme-kinetics

I am trying to understand how the inhibition constant is calculated for competitive inhibition.

$\frac{K^{app}}{V^{app}} = \frac{1+I/K_i}{V/K_m}$.

But often in secondary plots, $\frac{K^{app}}{V^{app}} $ vs Inhibitor concentration is plotted and the inhibition constant , $K_i$ is obtained from slope $1/K_i$. How is the slope equal to  $1/K_i$ from the above equation?
Could someone explain?